# issue with thumbnail overlay size on responsive grid

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm working with the foundation framework on a responsive portfolio site, seen here http://www.evanarussell.com/newsite

I'm in the process of implementing the thumbnail overlay style seen here http://lukashaider.com

My first attempt (as seen on the first two thumbnails on my site) involved using the css fade on the image inside of a div with background-color, but I couldn't get it to function correctly when the caption was added.

On the third thumbnail I've added the caption but I can't figure out how to get the overlay to fit the size of the image. It appears about 15px too wide on each side.

My goal is to have the caption as seen in thumbnail 3, with the overlay fitting the image like the first two thumbnails.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="large-4 medium-4 small-6 columns">
<div class="imagebg"><a title="block 1" href="#">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350&text=." class="fade"></a></div>
</div>

<div class="large-4 medium-4 small-6 columns">
<div class="imagebg"><a title="block 2" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350&text=."     class="fade"></a></div>
 </div>

  <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-6 columns">
  <a title="block 3" href="#">
  <div class="thumbcaption"><span>TEST CAPTION</span></div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350&text=.">
  </a>
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.fade {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .18s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .18s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .18s ease-in-out;
   }

   .fade:hover {
   opacity: 0.24;
   }

  .imagebg {
  background-color: rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.75);
  background-color: rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,      rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25)), color-stop(100%, #f5404d));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25), #f5404d);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25), #f5404d);
  }

.thumbcaption {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
opacity: 0;
background-color: rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.75);
background-color: rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(245,     64, 77, 0.25)), color-stop(100%, #f5404d));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25), #f5404d);
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25), #f5404d);
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
transition: all 0.2s linear;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }

.thumbcaption span {
padding: 0;
position: relative;
top: 52%;
opacity: 0;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
transition: all 0.4s ease; }

a:hover .thumbcaption {
opacity: 1; }
a:hover .thumbcaption span {
top: 48%;
opacity: 1; }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Clearly formatting the code would help you get better answers.

Comment: if you want better result always create a fiddle for people to play with your code. here http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution using foundation's block grid and this method with z-index:

http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

you can see the example here http://www.evanarussell.com/newsite

Everything seems to work when resizing the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a class for the images and then:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbcaption').css('width', $('.imageclass').width());
});
```

Should Work

Answer (score 0):

```
 The above annwer is not correct at all given by the user "http://stackoverflow.com/users/2865446/user2865446".

I have find out it .You mistakenly applied hover rule for the third div on <div> which is class="thumbcaption" instead of image.The other first two hover is applied on <img> tags.So please applied css rule on <img> tag to get your desire result.

Your css rule is for the third div

<div class="large-4 medium-4 small-6 columns">
<a href="#" title="block 3">
<div class="thumbcaption">
<span>TEST CAPTION</span>
</div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350&text=.">
</a>
</div>

You can see there is no class for the <img>tag which is applied for the ohter two.So please remove any hover style if you applied on the third div and add class for the third <div><img  class="fade" src="http://placehold.it/350&text=."> which is also applied on the ohter <img>elements of the rest <div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.I have tried using the "imagebg' div and "class="fade" on the last thumbnail, but it doesn't work with the caption on hover. The caption works fine, but the opacity on the thumbnail doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Check it may be helpful for you .I have given both html as well as css code 


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if IE 8]>               <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en" > <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Evan A. Russell &#124; Design & Direction &#124; New York City</title>


      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid-5.css">


      <script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Navigation -->

          <div class="row">
           <div class="large-12 columns">

    <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div id="logo">

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 14.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 43363)  -->

    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"

         width="49.298px" height="44.583px" viewBox="3 224.667 49.298 44.583" enable-background="new 3 224.667 49.298 44.583"

         xml:space="preserve">

    <path fill="#161616" d="M49.598,249.169c-0.138,0.12-0.294,0.241-0.465,0.354c-0.906-1.521-2.064-3.232-1.538-5.278h0.043

        c0.457,1.096,1.33,1.935,1.959,2.806c0.043,0.07,0.087,0.131,0.132,0.193l2.349-2.491c-0.037,1.107-0.417,2.41-1.255,3.25

        C50.333,248.381,50.032,248.785,49.598,249.169"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M49.797,246.222c-0.067-0.095-0.139-0.199-0.199-0.294c-1.062-1.528-2.001-3.411-1.789-5.554l0.02-0.044

        c0,0,0.05,0.044,0.05,0.14c0.561,0.707,1.253,1.434,1.718,2.211c0.132,0.217,0.243,0.439,0.338,0.674

        c0.508-0.985,1.442-1.487,1.986-2.359c0.061,0.112,0,0.19,0.095,0.346C52.155,243.388,51.17,244.927,49.797,246.222"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M6.649,239.377c-0.062,0.439-0.013,0.92-0.125,1.381c-0.095,0.191-0.171,0.386-0.255,0.584

        c-0.237,0.516-0.494,0.986-0.905,1.185c-0.291-0.666-0.549-1.373-0.575-2.19c0.051-0.531,0.186-1.021,0.398-1.484

        c0.334-0.727,0.855-1.368,1.534-1.908c0.021-0.019,0.039-0.026,0.051-0.04l0.103,0.002c-0.025,0.067-0.049,0.143-0.075,0.223

        C6.589,237.85,6.623,238.561,6.649,239.377"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M6.115,243.044c0.53-0.684,1.444-1.228,1.764-1.91L8,241.108c0.148,0.76-0.043,1.599-0.406,2.323

        c-0.425,0.95-1.061,1.632-1.479,2.565c-0.076,0.182-0.146,0.363-0.208,0.562c-1.266-1.348-2.391-2.825-2.407-4.822l2.333,1.789

        C5.902,243.354,6.003,243.191,6.115,243.044"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M5.815,253.735c0.103,0,0.2,0.01,0.3,0.018c0.97,0.078,1.893,0.27,2.637,0.692

        c0.043,0.017,0.077,0.041,0.122,0.068l1.172-3.343l0.018-0.061c0.079,0.061,0.173,0.155,0.25,0.284

        c1.323,1.582-0.631,3.768,0.166,5.52c-0.381-0.362-0.871-0.456-1.443-0.568c-0.093-0.043-0.191-0.079-0.284-0.124

        c-1.002-0.423-1.96-0.886-2.637-1.629c-0.233-0.261-0.429-0.555-0.585-0.899C5.642,253.675,5.702,253.675,5.815,253.735"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M14.944,263.522c0.078-0.034,0.165-0.061,0.24-0.087c0.779-0.25,1.564-0.457,2.342-0.525

        c0,0,0-0.052-0.04-0.131c-0.814-1.026-0.211-2.737-1.143-3.723l0.026-0.018c1.059,0.467,1.726,1.298,2.246,2.257

        c0.483,0.878,0.845,1.871,1.303,2.771c-0.43,0.018-0.873,0.104-1.303,0.217c-0.985,0.25-1.989,0.621-2.989,0.493

        c-0.146-0.034-0.294-0.07-0.443-0.105c-0.629-0.189-1.165-0.521-1.474-1.053C14.089,263.651,14.487,263.556,14.944,263.522"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M49.598,252.112c-0.569,0.381-1.312,0.623-2.003,0.71c-0.683-1.651-1.114-3.457-0.468-5.187l0.052-0.031

        c0.174,0.345,0.21,0.715,0.416,1.045c0.38,0.62,0.785,1.191,1.123,1.855c0.294-0.206,0.586-0.396,0.88-0.576

        c0.614-0.383,1.203-0.76,1.719-1.437c-0.241,1.236-0.552,2.454-1.301,3.284C49.882,251.896,49.746,252.009,49.598,252.112"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M10.869,257.719c0.189,0.052,0.369,0.104,0.542,0.164c-0.381-1.141,0.153-2.238,0.096-3.368l0.018-0.045

        c0.977,0.743,1.263,1.883,1.495,3.068c0.163,0.854,0.311,1.726,0.69,2.452c-0.233-0.053-0.456-0.087-0.69-0.12

        c-0.241-0.037-0.493-0.061-0.751-0.069c-0.483-0.115-0.96-0.233-1.4-0.38c-0.821-0.286-1.554-0.659-2.117-1.219

        c-0.258-0.258-0.484-0.562-0.658-0.907c0.208,0.026,0.433,0.053,0.658,0.08C9.46,257.461,10.203,257.554,10.869,257.719"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M4.01,245.704c0.915,0.396,1.474,1.114,2.105,1.726c0.019,0.018,0.027,0.028,0.037,0.043l1.847-2.848h0.071

        c1.062,2.22-1.062,3.695-1.191,5.655c-0.259-0.206-0.51-0.43-0.762-0.673c-0.474-0.451-0.956-0.941-1.476-1.372

        c-0.647-0.667-1.104-1.806-0.991-2.817C3.784,245.479,3.864,245.591,4.01,245.704"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M7.447,251.326c0.432-1.044,1.141-2.073,1.175-3.265l0.036-0.042l0.075,0.042

        c0.01,0.008,0.02,0.026,0.02,0.035c0.051,0.113,0.111,0.181,0.214,0.301c0.667,1.522,0.365,3.238-0.214,4.725

        c-0.094,0.243-0.19,0.477-0.304,0.711c-0.673-0.649-1.563-0.891-2.334-1.392c-0.067-0.051-0.133-0.095-0.207-0.149

        c-0.723-0.646-1.104-1.629-1.215-2.545c0.492,0.214,0.975,0.396,1.422,0.62C6.6,250.602,7.06,250.896,7.447,251.326"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M10.869,260.87c0.725,0.062,1.434-0.139,2.15-0.24c0.475-0.062,0.958-0.079,1.451,0.061

        c0.018-0.079,0.018-0.133,0-0.207c-0.699-1.029-0.208-2.539-0.855-3.49c0.224,0,0.32,0.146,0.571,0.189

        c0.431,0.242,0.752,0.57,0.999,0.967c0.745,1.149,0.874,2.799,1.488,3.999c-0.475-0.036-0.976,0-1.488,0.044

        c-0.715,0.061-1.45,0.146-2.166,0.052c-0.449-0.059-0.882-0.192-1.305-0.434c-0.241-0.181-0.683-0.421-0.845-0.718

        c-0.043-0.076-0.07-0.152-0.06-0.23C10.826,260.862,10.841,260.862,10.869,260.87"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M45.987,256.172c0,0,0-0.053-0.027-0.129c-0.431-1.797-1.018-3.844,0.19-5.38h0.044l0.58,1.869l0.404,1.299

        c0.692-0.361,1.626-0.552,2.42-0.666c0.293-0.043,0.571-0.068,0.812-0.094c-0.062,0.13-0.095,0.146-0.232,0.3

        c-0.163,0.322-0.357,0.598-0.58,0.839c-0.745,0.806-1.771,1.226-2.824,1.65C46.517,255.964,46.248,256.068,45.987,256.172"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M20.828,264.524c0.033-0.035,0.033-0.094,0.033-0.155c-0.381-0.26-0.568-0.751-0.871-1.21

        c-0.07-0.793-0.38-1.691-0.545-2.333c1.633,0.528,2.573,2.065,3.525,3.411c2.885,1.556,6.39,1.859,9.465,0.384

        c1.573-1.269,2.083-3.302,4.06-3.932c0.02,0.016,0.035,0.016,0.062,0.016c0,0.121-0.042,0.217-0.139,0.288

        c-0.173,1.373-0.966,2.487-1.459,3.306c0.889,0.217,1.718,0.605,2.582,0.83c0.501,0.129,1,0.207,1.536,0.156

        c-0.154,0.034-0.268,0.113-0.438,0.286c-0.347,0.242-0.717,0.413-1.099,0.525c-1.458,0.44-3.126-0.009-4.466-0.794

        c-1.13,0-2.383,0.361-3.205,0.854l3.095,0.968v0.174c-0.149,0.415-0.245,0.95-0.684,1.156c-1.158-0.604-2.505-1.079-3.662-1.711

        c-1.565,0.078-3.009,1.33-4.434,1.84c-0.128-0.052-0.249-0.077-0.267-0.129l-0.492-0.952c0.759-0.716,2.237-0.664,3.075-1.216

        c-1.029-0.494-2.237-0.641-3.377-0.968c-1.011-0.017-1.503,0.838-2.488,1.088c-0.614,0.148-1.348,0.155-2.021,0.008

        c-0.484-0.102-0.941-0.292-1.305-0.563c0.503-0.108,0.908-0.316,1.305-0.532C19.298,264.948,19.928,264.533,20.828,264.524"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M43.517,259.264c-0.282-0.017-0.561-0.042-0.803-0.066h-0.069c0.025-0.07,0.042-0.141,0.069-0.208

        c0.355-1.133,0.442-2.481,0.803-3.594c0.216-0.666,0.536-1.262,1.063-1.674h0.097l0.378,3.53l1.72-0.301l1.167-0.209

        c-0.469,0.293-0.797,0.77-1.167,1.235c-0.235,0.294-0.494,0.588-0.813,0.81C45.322,259.264,44.374,259.308,43.517,259.264"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M39.32,261.771c0.485-1.177,0.794-2.507,1.414-3.56c0.391-0.657,0.9-1.21,1.645-1.545

        c-0.383,0.896-0.494,2.216-0.477,3.167c0.268-0.034,0.538-0.023,0.812,0.011c0.268,0.026,0.536,0.076,0.803,0.146

        c0.631,0.139,1.254,0.319,1.824,0.319c-0.492,0.457-1.123,0.846-1.824,1.131c-0.257,0.104-0.523,0.189-0.803,0.268

        c-0.646,0.184-1.322,0.269-1.979,0.26C40.252,261.968,39.769,261.899,39.32,261.771"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M36.003,263.825c0.536-1.029,0.916-2.236,1.535-3.195c0.436-0.667,0.977-1.21,1.782-1.495h0.042

        c-0.646,1.08-0.439,2.333-0.793,3.491c0.673,0.215,1.433,0.491,2.167,0.602c0.5,0.079,0.995,0.079,1.418-0.066

        c-0.381,0.335-0.763,0.603-1.22,0.891c-0.06,0.05-0.129,0.093-0.199,0.136c-0.994,0.621-2.106,0.434-3.198,0.111

        C37.024,264.145,36.504,263.966,36.003,263.825"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M48.894,238.874c0.062,0.441,0.014,0.92,0.124,1.381c0.094,0.193,0.173,0.387,0.255,0.584

        c0.238,0.516,0.495,0.986,0.907,1.186c0.29-0.667,0.549-1.374,0.576-2.191c-0.051-0.529-0.188-1.021-0.401-1.483

        c-0.334-0.729-0.854-1.37-1.535-1.908c-0.019-0.021-0.035-0.025-0.046-0.041l-0.106,0.002c0.027,0.067,0.05,0.144,0.076,0.222

        C48.956,237.346,48.919,238.058,48.894,238.874"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M28.072,235.622c0,0-3.927,1.003-4.435,0.239c-0.507-0.761-1.108-2.959-3.188-5.333

        c-2.08-2.377-3.927-5.694-3.927-5.694s-4.472,2.538-1.433,11.388c0.277,0.806-0.415,1.479-0.415,2.643

        c0,1.167,2.309,3.363,2.309,3.363s-0.738,3.138-0.738,4.841c0,1.704,0.507,4.079,1.709,5.782c1.2,1.703,0.414,2.15,0.414,2.646

        c0,0.489,0.324,4.347,2.22,3.092c1.893-1.256,4.859-4.472,7.215-4.427C30.162,254.207,28.072,235.622,28.072,235.622"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M28.028,235.622c0,0,3.927,1.003,4.438,0.239c0.505-0.761,1.105-2.959,3.187-5.333

        c2.077-2.377,3.925-5.694,3.925-5.694s4.474,2.538,1.433,11.388c-0.276,0.806,0.418,1.479,0.418,2.643

        c0,1.167-2.31,3.363-2.31,3.363s0.737,3.138,0.737,4.841c0,1.704-0.507,4.079-1.707,5.782c-1.203,1.703-0.417,2.15-0.417,2.646

        c0,0.489-0.323,4.347-2.218,3.092c-1.892-1.256-4.942-4.472-7.298-4.427C25.859,254.207,28.028,235.622,28.028,235.622"/>

    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M28.052,235.601v9.384c0,0-3.423,4.303-3.699,5.333c-0.278,1.032-1.433,4.573-2.773,5.871

        c-1.338,1.301-2.383,2.421-2.679,1.886c-0.347-0.63-0.786-2.021-0.416-2.422c0.368-0.402,1.34-0.896,1.479-1.748

        c0.137-0.852,0.044-3.632,1.293-6.097c1.247-2.466,3.557-3.99,3.834-4.394c0.278-0.403-0.044-1.166-0.322-1.973

        c-0.277-0.807-1.02-3.447,0.277-5.242C25.37,235.749,28.052,235.601,28.052,235.601"/>

    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M28.047,235.577v9.383c0,0,3.421,4.304,3.699,5.334c0.277,1.031,1.433,4.574,2.772,5.876

        c1.339,1.297,2.4,2.425,2.681,1.881c0.299-0.585,0.785-2.018,0.415-2.421c-0.37-0.403-1.341-0.896-1.477-1.75

        c-0.14-0.851-0.047-3.629-1.295-6.097c-1.245-2.463-3.558-3.987-3.833-4.391c-0.276-0.404,0.046-1.167,0.323-1.973

        c0.277-0.807,1.018-3.448-0.277-5.244C30.73,235.727,28.047,235.577,28.047,235.577"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M28.211,249.892c0,0-4.158-0.045-4.342-1.704c-0.185-1.657,2.033-3.449,4.297-3.406

        c2.262,0.046,4.388,1.792,3.835,3.184C31.445,249.354,30.29,249.758,28.211,249.892"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M24.284,256.472c0,0,2.126,0.837,4.198,0.837c2.069,0,3.334-0.781,3.334-0.781s-1.324,1.228-2.128,1.395

        c-0.805,0.168-0.646,0.344-0.414,0.565c0.229,0.225-1.37-0.232-1.196-0.454c0.172-0.224-1.564-0.494-0.702,0.286

        c0.265,0.241-1.712-0.51-1.082-0.677C26.928,257.476,26.699,258.033,24.284,256.472"/>

    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M23.006,243.632c0.03,0.492-0.771,0.944-1.792,1.008c-1.021,0.064-1.874-0.282-1.903-0.774

        c-0.032-0.493,0.771-0.944,1.791-1.009C22.124,242.792,22.976,243.141,23.006,243.632"/>

    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M36.674,243.861c-0.042,0.491-0.903,0.815-1.92,0.726c-1.021-0.091-1.81-0.563-1.765-1.053

        c0.043-0.492,0.904-0.816,1.922-0.727C35.929,242.898,36.717,243.371,36.674,243.861"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M22.356,243.731c0.059,1.15-0.409,2.124-1.042,2.174c-0.635,0.05-1.198-0.844-1.255-1.995

        c-0.059-1.15,0.408-2.122,1.043-2.173C21.734,241.688,22.296,242.58,22.356,243.731"/>

    <path fill="#161616" d="M35.788,243.851c-0.076,1.148-0.622,2.022-1.217,1.953c-0.596-0.069-1.017-1.057-0.938-2.204

        c0.079-1.151,0.625-2.025,1.22-1.954C35.447,241.716,35.866,242.703,35.788,243.851"/>

    <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="28.074,244.224 26.369,236.269 29.778,236.127 "/>

    </svg>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="topnavarea">

    <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">

    <h6><span class="name">EVAN A. RUSSELL<span class="light"> // DESIGN & DIRECTION</span></span></h6>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <div class="panel">
            <h6 style="font-weight:700;"><a style="color: #0e0e0e;" href="#">WORK</a> <a class="nav" href="#">INFO</a></h6>
          </div>
        </div>

     </div>

                    <div style="margin-top: 1.8em;" class="row">

              <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-6 columns">
                <div class="imagebg"><a title="block 1" href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350&text=." class="fade"></a></div>
              </div>

              <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-6 columns">
                <div class="imagebg"><a title="block 2" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350&text=." class="fade"></a></div>
              </div>

















               <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-6 columns ">
               <a  href="http://lukashaider.com/projects/forever-in-decay">
              <div class="caption"><span>Forever in Decay</span></div>
              <img src="http://lukashaider.com/content/01-projects/11-forever-in-decay/thumb.jpg">
            </a>
                </div>
              </div>

























            </div>

          <!-- End Thumbnails -->


          <!-- Footer -->
     <br />
            <footer class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns"><hr />
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="large-6 columns">
                      <p><span class="light">&copy; COPYRIGHT EVAN A. RUSSELL</span></p>
                  </div>

                </div>
            </div>
          </footer>

          <!-- End Footer -->


        </div>
      </div>

      <script>
      document.write('<script src=' +
      ('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') +
      '.js><\/script>')
      </script>

      <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
      <!--

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.alerts.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.cookie.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.forms.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.joyride.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.section.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.interchange.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.placeholder.js"></script>

      <script src="js/foundation/foundation.abide.js"></script>

      -->

      <script>
        $(document).foundation();
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>



css code is below
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 91%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.75);
    background-color: rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25)), color-stop(100%, #f5404d));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25), #f5404d);
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25), #f5404d);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }

    .caption span {
      padding: 1rem;
      position: relative;
      top: 52%;
      opacity: 0;
      color: white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      transition: all 0.4s ease; }
  a:hover .caption {
    opacity: 1; }
     a:hover .caption span {
      top: 48%;
      opacity: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Image thumbnail looks like this .check it it may be the desire result
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works fine in a full-width browser window. I just can't figure out how to make the overlay scale with the thumbnail image when resizing the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to use media 
I used only case match like
@media  screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 400px) {
/* start>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
   Hi This is css code for caption and others css rules 
   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/    

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    width: 5%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.75);
    background-color: rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25)), color-stop(100%, #f5404d));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25), #f5404d);
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(245, 64, 77, 0.25), #f5404d);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }

    .caption span {
      padding: 1rem;
      position: relative;
      top: 25%;
      opacity: 0;
      color: white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 0.5em;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
      transition: all 0.4s ease; }
  a:hover .caption {
      width:65%;
    opacity: 1; }
     a:hover .caption span {
      top: 48%;
      font-size:40%;
      opacity: 1; }
/* end>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
   Hi This is css code for caption and others css rules 
   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<*/
}
```

[image]